# ESP32 with LNA and PA

Tags: amplifier, rf, schematics, esp8266, wifi

I would like to add a low noise amplifier and a power amplifier to the ESP32. As you may know there is only one RF output on the chip.

I was thinking of adding an RF switch, and switching between receiving (ANT to LNA to ESP32) and transmitting (ESP32 to PA to ANT).

Where you I place my switch on the schematic ? At the end (A) or at the beginning (B) ?

Also should I worry about PA output EMI being picked up by the LNA ?
[image]

Comment: How will you control the switch?

Comment: Using one of the ESP32's gpio